# Drupal 8: Form API/Webforms: multiple composite field on same page with states

Tags: forms, drupal-8

#### Help wanted

I'm struggling with the Form API/Webforms in Drupal 8.
I've made a couple of custom composite form elements that we use in a form. Some of the fields have a #states option. Here is a small example:

```
$elements['invoice_notice_of_default_file'] = [
  '#type' => 'file',
  '#title' => t('Voeg uw ingebrekestelling toe'),
  '#states' => [
    'visible' => [
      ':input[name="invoice_fields[invoice_notice_of_default]"]' => ['value' => 'yes'],
    ],
  ],
];
```

The problem with this is when I add more than 1 of the same composites on the same page, the name will have a number, like `invoice_fields_2[invoice_notice_of_default]`, `invoice_fields_3[invoice_notice_of_default]`. This will break the states because of the hardcoded name. Anybody know what can be done about this?

Thanks in advance!!